# I am trying to remove scayt option from ckeditor in sharepoint

Tags: ckeditor4, scayt

When i click on check spelling option, popup comes and it keeps loading.
I tried using
config.removePlugins='scayt'; in config.js file
and its not helping.

Answer (score 0):

in JS file `config.js`
in `config.toolbarGroups` do you try to remove `Scayt` ?